How insert Row Totals in Details area in SSRS
I have a SSRS 22 Report with two row groups and one column group:

I want to create proportions, but how can I get the total values into one column?

I tryied in the box expressions but it did not work.:
=count(Fields!StateProvince.Value, "CountryRegion") 
=count(Fields!StateProvince.Value, "StateProvince") 
=count(Fields!StateProvince.Value, "ModifiedDate") 


Are you using sql server for your data? Return a field that does the counting. something along the lines of count(countryregion) over (partition by countryregion) as regioncount. Then simply display the data here. But that is the point of displaying that total in the detail? What are you really trying to achieve?

I want creating proportions 5/50 for the first line for example. I need find a way to get the 50.

in that case, you can just go =  cstr( CountRows("StateProvince") )+" / "+cstr(CountRows("CountryRegion")) to get what you are after. If it works, let me know I will turn this into an answer.
